# Почему указатель со значением nil не эквивалентен nil при сравнении?

Tags: указатели, golang, golang-faq, дизайн-языка

Я прочитал раздел «[Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error)» из официально FAQ, но все-равно не понял. Вот пример:

```
func returnsError() error {
    var p *MyError = nil
    if bad() {
        p = ErrBad
    }
    return p // Will always return a non-nil error.
}
```

Как так, я же явно указываю что указатель должен ссылаться на недоступный участок памяти? Какая разница, какой у него тип?

Вот еще пример:

```
func Generate() *MyError {
    return nil
}

func Test() error {
    return Generate()
}

func main() {
    if Test() != nil {
        fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Этот пример выводит `Hello, world!` даже не смотря на то, что я явно передаю значение `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Как и написано в FAQ'е, интерфейсные значения по сути являются структурами из указателя на тип и указателя на данные. Пример компилируется в нечто вроде

```
err.type = *MyError
err.data = nil
return err
```

В то время как nil'евые интерфейсы выглядят вот так:

```
err.type = nil
err.data = nil
return err
```

Так как тип не нулевой, то и интерфейсное значение не нулевое. Иллюстрированное объяснение принципа работы интерфейсов можно почитать у Расса Кокса здесь: http://research.swtch.com/interfaces.

Comment: Но причем здесь интерфейсы? В контексте первой функции выше, я просто возвращаю указатель, который равен nil. Да, по сигнатуре функции я вижу что мой указатель будет будет приведен к типу `error`, но ничего не говорит о том, что это какой-то интерфейс. Получается, что каждый раз, когда я пишу `return`, я должен проверить приводится ли значение к какому-нибудь типу, и что этот тип не интерфейс?

Comment: Как это "ничего не говорит"? А [документация](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error)? Ничего проверять не нужно, просто когда хотите вернуть nil, так и пишите: `return nil`.

Comment: Во-первых, причем здесь документация? `error` просто как пример, это может быть любой тип, который может являться интерфейсом, а может и нет, т.е. получается, что мне каждый раз нужно удостовериться? Во-вторых, я же не зря указал что в контексте "ничего не говорит", и это действительно так, в сигнатуре это никак не отражается. В-третьих, я почти так и делаю, просто я возвращаю значение nil, которое хранится в переменной. Получается что в Go есть принципиальная разница, возвращать значение константой или как значение переменной?

Comment: Как это должно работать по-вашему? `nil` сам по себе не имеет типа. Это **не** просто нулевой указатель. Присваиваете указателю - будет нулевой указатель, одно машинное слово. Присваиваете интерфейсу - будет нулевой интерфейс, два слова. Присваиваете слайсу, будет нулевой слайс, три слова. Вы присвоили указателю, а потом указатель конвертируется в возвращаемый тип, интерфейс.

Comment: @saintech, просто рассматривайте интерфейсы как `struct{TypePtr, ValuePtr ...}`. Да, кстати, `error` - это самый настоящий [интерфейс](https://godoc.org/builtin#error), просто он встроенный. Любой тип, что имеет метод `Error() string` автоматически является типом `error`. В то время как преобразование типа не к интерфейсу таким суб-эффектами не [обладает](http://play.golang.org/p/VyMSdxrbk7)